# 4.7.3 Vs 4.6.14

Tags: upgrade

I am a complete CiviCRM noob I am the ICT adviser to a small non-profit Paramedic service. We are going to be using CiviCRM to replace a ancient filemaker database.

I thought I was doing the right thing and installing the latest version of CiviCRM but it seem that just about none of the extension are compatible with 4.7.3

Am I missing something should I have installed 4.6.14 instead, if so is there a way to downgrade without having to start again?

I would not be to concerned but much of the features we are looking for are only covered by extensions

thanks in advance

Zeak

Comment: Why not be specific about the Extensions you have in mind.

Comment: BTW i opened this ticket here to try and crowdsource more info about which extensions are known to work on 4.7.x http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/which-extensions-are-you-using-with-4-7-which-do-not-yet-state-they-have-a-4-7-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, 4.7 is a "development" release. 4.6 is a "long term support (LTS) release". Most people would recommend 4.6 (or even 4.4!) for very stable websites, and only using 4.7 if you need the latest features or are developing for the future.

As an extension contributor myself, there's a reasonable functionality jump between 4.6 and 4.7, so it may be some time until every extension is on there, and some may never get there. It depends on the extension and the developers who maintain them.

Unfortunately, there is no way to "downgrade". Your best options are to:

1) Manually download and install the extensions, put them in the extensions directory, and then test them. They will probably mostly work, but you will need to do this testing yourself.

2) Contact the developers of the key extensions, asking them for a timeframe of when they will be supporting 4.7

3) Hire a freelancer or agency to update them to 4.7 for you. I would be more than happy to do this - http://civifirst.com, or you could look for a partner agency at http://civicrm.org/partners-contributors.

4) If you do decide to move to 4.6, you can easily export and import your configurations and data. If you find yourself needing to do this, do ask here in a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did not realize that 4.7.3 was more a developer release, we are going for stable as possible so if the main herd is going with 4.6 then we will do the same

Comment: Difference of opinion. I don't agree with JohnFF's assessment re 4.7 as a 'developer' version. It is the version the civi core team provide as the default download. And I certainly would not be recommending 4.4.x as it is uncertain if all security issues will be addressed for that release.

Comment: i wanted to 'edit' the above as i shouldn't assume it is John's assessment.  he may well be quoting from other sources/discussion. But if that is the commonly held view, then I think the core documentation should be clearer about that. Certainly nothing as such is stated eg https://civicrm.org/blogs/yashodha/civicrm-470-is-out

Comment: I might clarify here: "developer version" might have been the wrong phrasing:
It isn't an LTS version. It contains up to date latest features but is in flux and is liable to change lots and soon!
LTS versions are much less transient.
When I said "for the future" I meant for a long project likely to be released not imminently.
I thought 4.4 was still being supported WRT security features? Is that not the case?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Extensions, and we (Fuzion) have contributed a fair few of them, I think it is fair to say that in our case, since all our clients are still on 4.6.x, we simply have not had cause to see what breakages might happen with 4.7.

We build extensions with the long-term in mind and since Eileen is very much part of the team outside of core that is helping with that long-term view (and building API etc) i would expect our extensions to be as future-proofed as was possible at the time of the original build.

It can be really helpful to the community if you and others can help push these community assets forward by doing some testing of Extensions on 4.7 and reporting back via their git repository as to how much the fail/succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the Information, I will post another question about getting my data and settings out before downgrading